# User keyword substitution cipher looping over two different sized arrays

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

Been programming for 4 weeks go easy on me...

**Aim:** I need to take a user input "keyword" and use this keyword in an alphabet cipher.

**Example:** User provides keyword "SALT."

**Cipher:** SALTBCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRUVWXYZ. (keyword + remaining alphabet letters)

I have made my string keyword into a char array and I have an alphabet array. I wanted the code to loop over both arrays and if the alphabet letter was not present (equal to) the keyword letters then it would add it on to the end of the keyword.

Issues - I am getting an ArrayOutOfBoundsException - which I believe it due to both my arrays being different sizes? Not sure how to fix that. Also would I need to create a third array to hold the keyword + remaining alphabet letters as arrays cant change size? I can only use Arrays nothing else (Lists, Hashsets etcs as I've not learned them yet). Thanks for any help..

```
    char[] arr = keyWord.toCharArray();
    for (char c:arr) {
        System.out.println(c); //printing to see if it worked   
    }

    char [] alphabet = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
            'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
            'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
            };

    System.out.println(alphabet);

    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <alphabet.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <keyWord.length(); j++) {

            if (alphabet[j] != arr[i]) 
            //if alpha letter is not equal to keyword letters
            flag = false;
            break;
            }
            if (flag)
            //(false) just trying to print anything so
            // i can see whats happening..
                System.out.println(alphabet[i]);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: full code posted and yeah java, sorry!

Comment: Yeah it is thanks im not getting the exception anymore. Ive also renamed the "char arr" so its easier for me to keep track of. Can you advise if i need a third array to store the keyword and remaining letters? im not quite sure where to go from here. thanks

Comment: my advice, use a new array to store the cipher described in your question ( not a good name, too. Must be the key or something else depends how you use it) generate it into an array. So, you don't need to recalculate it whenever you need.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 3):

There are some variable naming problems that confuse you. Replace `keyWord` with `arr` in the loop range control, since you are using `arr` now. Then, you can see that `arr` must be indexed by `j` not `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <alphabet.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <arr.length(); j++) { //---------> notice me

        if (alphabet[i] != arr[j])  //---------> notice me, too
            //if alpha letter is not equal to keyword letters
            flag = false;
            break;
    }
    if (flag)
    //(false) just trying to print anything so
    // i can see whats happening..
    System.out.println(alphabet[i]);

}
```

Comment: The key here is matching each index with the correct array.